# Retrieving input value of innerHTML in JavaScript doesn't work properly in IE 9 and above

Tags: javascript, jsp, internet-explorer, innerhtml

I've ran into an issue with my JSP web application between IE version 9 and above vs. IE version 7, 8, and Quirks mode. In IE version below 9, when I update the value of an input text field in a table and look at the innerHTML of the table in JavaScript, I can see that the value for the input text field within the innerHTML has been updated to the new value that I entered on the page. However, when I look at the innerHTML value for the input text field for IE 9 and above, the value will remain what the value was when the page loads. Somehow the innerHTML value doesn't get updated in IE 9 and above but does so below IE 9, and I was wondering if there's a specific reason for the differences between browser version.

Comment: `if there's a specific reason for the differences between browser version` http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/184449/91155

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value *property* is supposed to reflect the *current* value, while the value *attribute* reflects the *default* value.

This bug was fixed in more recent versions of IE. Quirks mode emulates the big that older versions suffered from.

Comment: So the value attribute is what you would get on the innerHTML, whereas the value property is what you would get when you do document.getElementById('inputField').value?

Comment: Yes. You also get the attribute value with `document.getElementById('inputField').getAttribute('value')`